# Using strsplit results in terms with quotation marks in r

Tags: r, strsplit

I have a large set of data, which I have imported from excel. I wish to get term frequency table for the data set. But, when I use strspplit, it includes quotation marks and other punctuation which gives wrong results.

There is a small error in the way I am using strsplit and need help on the same as I am not able to figure it out myself.

> df = read_excel("C:/Users/B M Consulting/Documents/Book2.xlsx", col_types=c("text","numeric"), range=cell_cols("A:B"))
>
> vect <- c(df[1])
>
> vectsplit <- strsplit(tolower(vect), "\s+")
>
> vectlev <- unique(unlist(vectsplit))
>
> vecttermf <- sapply(vectsplit, function(x) table(factor(x, levels=vectlev)))

The output vect is something like this:

[1] "3 inch c clamp"             "baby vice"                  "baby vice bench"            "baby vise"
 [5] "bench"                      "bench vice"                 "bench vice clamp"           "bench vise"
 [9] "bench voice"                "bench wise"                 "bench wise heavy"           "bench wise table"
[13] "box for tools"              "c clamp"                    "c clamp set"                "c clamps"
[17] "carpenter tools"            "carpenter tools low price"  "cast iron pipe"             "clamp"
[21] "clamp set"                  "clamps woodworking"         "g clamp"                    "g clamp set 3 inch"

I need to get each word out. When I use strplit, it includes all the punctuation marks.

Below is a small section of vectsplit that I get. It includes all inverted commas, backslashes and commas which I dont want.

[1] "c(\"3"          "inch"           "c"              "clamp\","       "\"baby"         "vice\","        "\"baby"         "vice"
  [9] "bench\","       "\"baby"         "vise\","        "\"bench\","     "\"bench"        "vice\","        "\"bench"        "vice"
 [17] "clamp\","       "\"bench"        "vise\","        "\"bench"        "voice\","       "\"bench"        "wise\","        "\"bench"
 [25] "wise"           "heavy\","       "\"bench"        "wise"           "table\","       "\"box"          "for"            "tools\","
 [33] "\"c"            "clamp\","       "\"c"            "clamp"          "set\","         "\"c"            "clamps\","      "\"carpenter"
 [41] "tools\","       "\"carpenter"    "tools"          "low"            "price\","       "\"cast"         "iron"           "pipe\","

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the class of vect, you'll notice that it's not a character vector, but a list.

```
vect<-c(df[1])
class(vect)
> "list"
```

If you define vect as below, the issue disappears:

```
vect<-df[[1]]
class(vect)
> "character"
```

If you define vect as such and then use strsplit, it should work just fine. Keep in mind that different kinds of subsetting ([1] vs. [[1]]) will produce different classes of outputs.

Comment: Thank you very much, helped alot.